# Python error with a regex to match float

Tags: python, regex

I have this data:

```
1.2 GHz___(528)
1.3 GHz___(417)
1.4 GHz___(102)
1.5 GHz___(174)
1.6 GHz___(30)

528 MHz___(66)
533 MHz___(9)
550 MHz___(3)
600 MHz___(87)
624 MHz___(6)
```

and I have this regex:

```
(\d{1,4})((,|.)(\d{1,2})){0,1}
```

It works well for the Mhz value but unfortunately it doesn't work well for the Ghz value:

that's the output that I get and I can't understand what's wrong:

```
1.2.2 
1.3.3 
1.4.4
1.5.5
1.6.6
528
533
550
600
624
```

The output that I want is:

```
1.2
1.3
1.4
1.5
1.6
528
533
550
600
624
```

Comment: What's your actual code that you're using to get the output? What output do you want?

Comment: This looks like an issue of too many capture groups in relation to the particular code you're using to get them.

Comment: Does this really need regex? Can't you just read the first entry and convert it?

Comment: Why not just get the first space-delimited value on each line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this pattern

```
^(\d+(?:[,.]\d+)?)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yW4aZ3/270)

Answer (score 3):

Why not just get the first space-delimited value on each line?

```
def parse_data(data):
    for line in data:
        if line:
            yield line.split()[0]

data = """
1.2 GHz___(528)
1.3 GHz___(417)
1.4 GHz___(102)
1.5 GHz___(174)
1.6 GHz___(30)

528 MHz___(66)
533 MHz___(9)
550 MHz___(3)
600 MHz___(87)
624 MHz___(6)"""

numbers = list(parse_data(data.splitlines()))

print(numbers)
```

If you really want a regex, you could do this:

```
import re

re_numbers = re.findall('^(\d+(?:[,.]\d+)?)', data, re.MULTILINE)

print(re_numbers)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this pattern to get all numeric values(+ve, -ve, float, int):

`(?P<value>[-+]?[0-9]*[.]?[0-9]+|[0-9]+)`